# Using multiple layouts breaks orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-orientation

I've succeeded in handling configuration change with fragments, but I only used one XML layout for the container.

Now I need to use a layout for landscape mode, and when I turn my phone and try to change currently displayed fragments I get an error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1328)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1346)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:729)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:705)
```

Here are my two layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

And for the landscape one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

As you can see both are the exact same except for the orientation.
I guess the problem might come from reusing old fragments which were added using another orientation ?

Thanks for your help

Edit:
Code for my activity

```
package crysteo.pluggicontroller;

public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements StateModifier,IpAddressChangedListener {

private RemoteFragment remoteFragment;
private MainFragment mainFragment;
private DeviceListFragment deviceListFragment;
private RetainedFragment retainedFragment;
private HandleConnection handleConnection;
private ConnectedFragment connectedFragment;
private CameraFragment cameraFragment;
private final PluggiHandler handler = new PluggiHandler(this);


private static class PluggiHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MainFragmentActivity> mainFragmentActivityWeakReference;

    public PluggiHandler(MainFragmentActivity mainFragmentActivity) {
        this.mainFragmentActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(mainFragmentActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        MainFragmentActivity mainFragmentActivity = this.mainFragmentActivityWeakReference.get();
        BluetoothConstants.BluetoothMessageWhat msgEnum = BluetoothConstants.BluetoothMessageWhat.values()[msg.what];
        switch (msgEnum) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                BluetoothConstants.BluetoothStates argEnum = BluetoothConstants.BluetoothStates.values()[msg.arg1];
                switch (argEnum) {
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        mainFragmentActivity.connected();
                        break;
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Toast.makeText(mainFragmentActivity.getApplicationContext(), R.string.connecting_bluetooth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                /*byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);*/
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                /*byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);*/
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                Toast.makeText(mainFragmentActivity, String.format(mainFragmentActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.connected_bluetooth),
                        msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                if (null != mainFragmentActivity) {
                    Toast.makeText(mainFragmentActivity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        mainFragmentActivity.connected();
    }
}

;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        retainedFragment = new RetainedFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(retainedFragment, RetainedFragment.class.toString());
        handleConnection = new HandleConnection(this, handler);
        retainedFragment.setHandleConnection(handleConnection);

        deviceListFragment = new DeviceListFragment();
        remoteFragment = new RemoteFragment();
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        connectedFragment = new ConnectedFragment();
        cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_layout_container, mainFragment, MainFragment.class.toString());
    } else {
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainFragment.class.toString());
        deviceListFragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DeviceListFragment.class.toString());
        remoteFragment = (RemoteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(RemoteFragment.class.toString());
        retainedFragment = (RetainedFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(RetainedFragment.class.toString());
        connectedFragment = (ConnectedFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ConnectedFragment.class.toString());
        cameraFragment = (CameraFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CameraFragment.class.toString());

        if (mainFragment == null)
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();

        if (deviceListFragment == null)
            deviceListFragment = new DeviceListFragment();

        if (remoteFragment == null)
            remoteFragment = new RemoteFragment();

        if (connectedFragment == null)
            connectedFragment = new ConnectedFragment();

        if (cameraFragment == null)
            cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();

        handleConnection = retainedFragment.getHandleConnection();
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mainFragment.setBluetoothListener(handleConnection);
    if (retainedFragment.getSelectedMac() != null)
        mainFragment.onMacAddressChanged(retainedFragment.getSelectedMac());
    remoteFragment.setHandleConnection(handleConnection);
    mainFragment.setStateModifier(this);
    deviceListFragment.setStateModifier(this);
    deviceListFragment.setMacAddressChangedListener(mainFragment);
    connectedFragment.setStateModifier(this);
    connectedFragment.setIpAddressChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    retainedFragment.setHandleConnection(handleConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void listDevices() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_layout_container, deviceListFragment, DeviceListFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("listDevices");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void deviceSelected(String macAddress) {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    retainedFragment.setSelectedMac(macAddress);
    mainFragment.onMacAddressChanged(macAddress);
}

@Override
public void connected() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_layout_container, connectedFragment, ConnectedFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("connected");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void remoteControl() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(connectedFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_layout_container, cameraFragment, CameraFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_layout_container, remoteFragment, RemoteFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("manualMode");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void soundsControl() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_layout_container, cameraFragment, CameraFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("soundControl");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void infoDisplay() {

}

@Override
public void onIpChangedListener(String ip) {
    cameraFragment.setIp(ip);
}
}
```

And for the fragment which should be displayed:

```
public class ConnectedFragment extends Fragment {

private StateModifier stateModifier;
private IpAddressChangedListener ipAddressChangedListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connected_fragment_layout, container, false);

    root.findViewById(R.id.remote_control_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stateModifier.remoteControl();
        }
    });

    root.findViewById(R.id.sounds_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stateModifier.soundsControl();
        }
    });

    final EditText editText = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.ip_edit_text);

    root.findViewById(R.id.change_ip_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ipAddressChangedListener.onIpChangedListener(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    return root;
}

public void setStateModifier(StateModifier stateModifier) {
    this.stateModifier = stateModifier;
}

public void setIpAddressChangedListener(IpAddressChangedListener ipAddressChangedListener) {
    this.ipAddressChangedListener = ipAddressChangedListener;
}
}
```

Comment: Post your code from activity and fragment. The problem is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem came from my HandleConnection object. I didn't update the reference to the handler, which means that the handler called was referring to an already destroyed activity.

I found that by using commitAllowingStateLoss() in my fragment transaction. Instead of getting only a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`
 I got a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed` error which allowed me to guess what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that the Bluetooth connection message event invokes your `connected()` method which then performs a fragment transaction to display the `ConnectedFragment`.

So this is what is happening:

- User rotates device
- Activity starts shutting down, state is saved
- Connected event occurs (since activity hasn't totally shut down yet)
- Fragment transaction is attempted, but state has already been saved

You now have a race condition.

You will need to manage those fragment transactions more carefully.  I would recommend starting with adding this code at the beginning of `connected()` and anywhere else an event could cause a fragment transaction:

```
    if (isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }
```

Then you won't attempt a fragment transaction when the activity's state has (probably) already been saved.

This single code snippet might not solve all your problems.  You will probably need to add some lifecycle logging to analyze what is happening when.  Then you can add the necessary code to ensure things happen in the correct sequence.

Incidentally: This code

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

is redundant; the `FragmentActivity`'s `onBackPressed` method already handles checking the fragment back stack and popping it if necessary.  Maybe you were going to add some more custom back button handling?

Comment: Thanks kris, I haven't got time yet to try your suggestion but my bluetooth connection only occurs when the user presses a button. I think that means that there can't be any race condition (or I don't understand anything about that) ? The problem appeared after adding the second layout for landscape mode, but otherwise it worked before (I'll still take those advice into account to avoid any future crash by the way !).

Comment: The problem arises because you don't have any control over a) when  BlueTooth is going to complete the connection and b) when the user is going to rotate the device.  Those rotations can happen spuriously -- I put the device on my desk, say, and the movement causes a rotation.  It's a wicked problem and probably 90% of my testing is just for these conditions because the majority of my bugs are crashes on rotation.